# Query Assistance selecting subselect

Tags: mysql

I have a table `locations` that has a `rating double` column and a `state varchar` column. I also have a `reviews` table that has a column `locid` which connects (foreign key) a review record to the `locations` table column `id`

I currently have this query, which populates 5 random clubs based on having a `rating >= 3.5` and `a state of FL`

```
select * 
  from locations 
 where rating > 3.5 
   and state='FL' 
group by name 
order by rand() 
limit 5
```

I need to grab now 1 review generated from the query above for each of 5 location records. The caveat is I would need to make sure that the locations selected do in fact have atleast one record in the reviews table.

so the final query would have the location query above with a confirmation that one record exists in reviews table then i do a subsequent query againstr the reviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use an `EXISTS` clause to check for the presence of a review, and then `JOIN` these results to the `reviews` table to get the actual review:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM locations l
      WHERE rating > 3.5
        AND state = 'FL'
        AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM reviews r WHERE r.locid = l.id)
      ORDER BY RAND()
      LIMIT 5
     ) loc
JOIN reviews r
ON r.locid = loc.id
```

I'm not sure why you have a `GROUP BY` clause in your query? Can a location have more than one entry in the `locations` table?